# Coding magazines

Tags: resources

So, we have [coding books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read), [coding RSS feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119/what-are-the-best-rss-feeds-for-programmersdevelopers), and [music to code by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947/coding-music).  Are there any coding magazines that anyone would recommend?

Comment: Awarded McKenzieG1 the win based on votes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The venerable [Dr. Dobbs Journal](http://www.ddj.com/) is still pretty good. It covers multiple platforms, and mixes some fairly hard-core technical articles with lighter fare (interviews with notables, a "Developer Diaries" column that profiles regular-Joe (and Jane) developers from a range of fields). If you are employed and have authority to spend some non-trivial amount of money on tools (or are willing to claim that you do), you can probably get them to send it to you for free.

For the Microsoft world, [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/default.aspx) is very useful. Some of their columns are excellent, particularly Jeff Richter's [Concurrent Affairs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc501041.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

The Pragmatic Programmers' [Pragmatic Bookshelf](http://pragprog.com/) publishes a [***free*** magazine](http://pragprog.com/magazines#) available online and for download in various formats:

> Each month, our editor Michael Swaine
>   brings you a free magazine packed full
>   of interesting articles, features, and
>   departments. Download it in PDF, mobi
>   (good for the Kindle), and epub (great
>   for Stanza on the iPhone).

Answer (score 5):

I also enjoy Dr. Dobb's Journal.  But hey, there's a way to leech it for free (at the time of writing, anyway):

http://pages.nxtbook.com/nxtbooks/cmp/ddj<mm><yy>/offline/cmp_ddj<mm><yy>_pdf.zip

Replace <mm> and <yy> with month and year.  They're available 8/2006 thru 2/2009.

Afterwards, it's known as Dr. Dobb's Digest and is instead available at URL pattern:

http://i.cmpnet.com/ddj/digest/<yyyy>/DDD_<mm><yy>.pdf

Answer (score 4):

[Dr. Dobbs Journal](http://ddj.com) is a pretty good broad-based programmer's journal.  Covers all manner of material.

Answer (score 2):

[Game Developer Magazine](http://www.gdmag.com/) has lots of very good articles, though as you might expect they tend to skew towards C++.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/) has some gems every once in awhile

Answer (score 2):

I like [Dr. Dobb's Journal](http://www.ddj.com/) also but the magazine refers the reader to their web site for most of the interesting articles.  I have found the [Java Developer's Journal](http://java.sys-con.com/) very interesting because it contains articles about Java in the context of both web and enterprise applications.

Answer (score 2):

For the Perl crowd, there is of course [The Perl Review](http://www.theperlreview.com/).  And for the German-speaking subset of it, there's the [Foo Magazin](http://www.perl-magazin.de/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

VSJ, I find it a great mag :) http://www.vsj.co.uk/

#### Edit

This is NOT off-topic! It directly relates to programming!

Answer (score 1):

I subscribe to MSDN magazine, it's a bit thinner now than in years past, but for .NET it covers a variety of topics, it's a good way to keep abreast of new Microsoft offerings.

All the content is available online on MSDN, and of course online resources/blogs are a lot more up to date, but sometimes it's nice to have a magazine in your bag for a flight or layover.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy [IEEE Software](http://www.computer.org/portal/site/software/) because it covers broader issues regarding software engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely [Your Sinclair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Sinclair). Hands down.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy [Code](http://www.code-magazine.com/) and [asp.netPRO](http://www.aspnetpro.com/) ... Visual Studio is so-so.

Answer (score 1):

The [ACCU](http://accu.org/) mags, [Overload](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c78/) and [C-Vu](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c77/).

I like [Game Developers Magazine](http://www.gdmag.com/), but since the ECTS no longer runs I no longer get free ones anymore:-(

Comment: Are they really good , i am planning to request our library to subscribe to them ?

Comment: They are a little thin but interesting reading.

Answer (score 1):

[Python Magazine](http://pymag.phparch.com/) of course ! BTW they are looking for contributors...

Answer (score 0):

I like Embedded Systems.  Even if you don't program for embedded systems, the software articles are excellent.  http://www.embedded.com/

Answer (score 0):

Both the IEEE and ACM put out a number of good computing magazines, which might be of interest depending on your exact interests. I'm a subscriber to both.

Answer (score 0):

The ACM Queue has some hardcore content, dense, but good. I haven't read it in a while though.

Answer (score 0):

For Delphi delvelopers "Blaise" international magazine - [www.blaisepascal.eu](http://www.blaisepascal.eu/)