# Is there an MSDN-type Developer Magazine for iOS Developers?

Tags: ios

I have already checked this thread - [Coding Magazines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346/coding-magazines) - but it has nothing specific for iOS Developer (iPhone, iPad app developers).

So... can anyone recommend a monthly iOS developer magazine (does it even exist?) for keeping up to date on iOS development, that is very similar in content to how the MSDN magazine is for Microsoft platform developers?

Also, [I am a blogger](http://oObly.com) myself and do ready blogs on Microsoft as well as iOS and other technologies. So don't tell me to go read blogs.

I am specifically looking for the MSDN Mag equivalent for iOS, if it exists.

Comment: Should be moved to programmers, but my mistake I voted for "not a real question", sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read MacTech Magazine? http://www.mactech.com it not all about iOS but they do discuss MacOS programming and Mac related stuff (i.e. iPhone) in some of their issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is no house organ magazine like MSDN Mag for iOS, I've looked as well.  There are a number of blogs related to the subject, but nothing like the detailed insider info you'd get out of MSDN.  Then again Apple has an extensive library of sample code and videos available to all devs; perhaps they feel that is sufficient.