# Software development process for small teams

Tags: architecture, project-management

I might be an exception here but I have never worked on a team with more than three developers and / or five people. Still we could manage to get the job done (somehow).

Is there a software development process which fits this "extreme" scenario? And, if you work as a standalone programmer is there something you can adapt to your daily life to make it more predicatable, coherent, documented and still get the job done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [agile methodologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) are a good starting point because, imho, they are better suited for small groups.

As for keeping your personal working pace I'd recommend a method based on TODO lists and some tool like [Task2Gather](http://www.task2gather.com/). You might want to look at [GTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done), too.

Things I would never give up even for a team of me:

- source version control
- backups
- TODO
- unit testing/[TDD](http://babilsenior.blogspot.com/2008/10/test-driven-development1-eng.html)
- code documentation
- refactoring/code reviews

Comment: @Manrico: As a team of 1 (me) also, I do source control, backups and have todos but not unit testing (apart from just trying my web apps manually through a few common scenarios) and code reviews. Do you have any advice on how I can start to add these? A blog about your process would be awesome! ;)

Comment: @Sprogz: here you are (it's just a draft) http://babilsenior.blogspot.com/2008/10/test-driven-development1-eng.html

Comment: @Manrico: Thanks very much! I've read a number of texts about the theory of TDD but I'm really missing hands-on examples of how ordinary developers are using it to help their development process. Your blog post was helpful and I'm very interested to read more! Nice work. I'll bookmark your blog.

Comment: I really think "Staffing" is not a factor...Agile is to minimise cost, not incur. It is a style, not rule. 5 or 500, agile can always be good :) for all the engineers involved. You can have a tailored-Agile (i.e. not all the practices are required for your purpose) but still maintain good programming practice for your final product.

Answer (score 6):

Let the mighty [SecretGeeek](http://www.secretgeek.net) teach you [how to be a standalone programmer](http://www.secretgeek.net/howtobeaprogrammer.asp). Enjoy :)

```
   intellisense 
        ||
        \/
       code >>> compile >>>>> run >>>> success >>>> profit ;-)
        /\         ||          ||         
        ^^         \/          \/
        ^^      errors       errors 
        ^^          \\       //
        ^^           \\     //
        ^^             google
        ^^              ||
        \\              \/
         \<<<<<<<  copy N paste
```

Comment: Change the last part to "success >>>> ? >>>> profit" and I'm sold.

Comment: I guess that's why not all developers are rich... I'm still looking for that bridge between success in development and profit.

Answer (score 5):

## [TODO driven development](http://www.secretgeek.net/howtobeaprogrammer.asp)

A *serious* suggestion from [SecretGeek](http://www.secretgeek.net).

Set up your development environment or editor to automatically list all lines with TODO tags - Visual Studio does this by default.

### Step 1

- Write Class or method outlines (ie, 'Public Class ...' or 'Public Sub...' with no code inside.)
- Include rough logic
- Add pseudo code preprended with "TODO:"
- Only write the *very* trivial code -- anything else just add a TODO

### Step 2

- Repeat step 1 until the whole application is roughed out
- You've now got a big list of 'TODO' tasks
- Check for completeness (breadth)
- See what can be removed.
- See what can be simplified (eg, two similar todo comments: can they be made identical?

### Step 3

- Replace TODO's with calls to non-existant classes, methods etc... 
  (For test driven development, create exhaustive tests for each of these methods/classes)

### Step 4

- Fix One Compilation error at a time by:

  - writing shells of classes, methods etc,
  - Adding TODO: pseudo code to each of these as you go.
  - (Also Add 'HACK: ' comments and explanations where appropriate, if pressed for time)
  - Where appropriate, replace TODO's with the trivial code required

### Step 5

- Repeat Step 4 until there are no compilation errors left.
- If there are TODO's left, then Go back to step 3.

*(There's also a lot of prior planning, paper prototyping, customer meetings, discussion, procrastination, database design, coffee-drinking, code-generation for sprocs and crud-sproc calls, import of re-usable DAL's, PAG block usage, go PAG!, back-and-forth debates prior to document sign-off, arguments, late-nights, frustration, chatting with friends, sifting through email, scratching in visio, printing things out and leaving them in a heap, scrounging for staples, catching buses, doing back and neck stretches etc., but that's all been left out for simplicity...)*

(MarkJ again) A bit like the pseudo-code programming process from [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com). And [we all agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) everyone should read Code Complete, right?

Comment: This is really straightforward and, even though it seems to be rather clunky, it works when developing alone a huge project where you can no longer remember what is missing

Answer (score 4):

Most of the agile methodologies fit your profile.

The most popular is currently [SCRUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)). It's designed for productivity in small teams, and it's fans claim that development times are 5-10 times better than the traditional waterfall methodologies.

I recommend the [Headfirst Software Development](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsd/) book if you want to get started on some reading

Comment: Scrum is what I'm currently doing with my team. I admit some of its tenets are a bit theatrical, but we're getting better at it. Now that you mention it... WE FORGOT OUR DAILY MEETING! :O

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend the [Crystal Clear](http://www.agilekiwi.com/crystal_clear.htm) method

The Seven Properties

- Frequent delivery/integration using time-boxed iterations
- Reflect and improve, criticise and fix
- Osmotic (passive) knowledge acquisition and communication through office organisation and open channels
- Personal Safety, safe to be honest, confidence to court criticism
- Stay focused, clear tasks, priorities on work, limit the workload
- Access to expert users, fast, quality feedback
- The usual agile stuff: automated testing, CM, continuous integration

Comment: For a split second I thought you were suggesting this: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/FrontAhead-Design.aspx <b>:D :D</b>

Comment: Crystal clear worked for me even better than Scrum did (and I'm a CSM)

Answer (score 2):

Development processes are basically created for large teams to avoid possible chaos. If you're trying to do large projects by yourself, you will fail no matter what development process you use, as you'll need large numbers to accomplish what's needed in time.

If you work on small projects, then any Agile method should do. GTD is no method, it's a method wannabe. It's like me patenting my brain process.

Comment: There has to be an accepable (amount of work)/(number of people in team) ratio, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but Steve McConnell has an article named [Less is More](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/articles/art06.htm) written more than a decade ago about why small teams are more productive.

Comment: Quite a nice article but really away from the main theme of the question. Currently working on a 11 people team and finding it very demanding in terms of communication.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous Integration is the first thing I always try to get set up on teams I work on as I believe it is the foundation of good development practices i.e. Integrate often, automated build/release, self testing build, easy for anyone to get latest.

Read more about it here:
http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

Comment: You know, continuous integration is something the whole company could benefit from, but I can't see it saving a lot of work for tiny teams - from 1 to 5 people - as long as they communicate a lot - at least not as much work as it takes to get it up and running.

Comment: There are tools out there that take the work out of setting it up (teamcity).  It is up to you whether you choose to implement it but it is one of the first things I try to get set up when working with a large project as I think it is vital.  Having a one click build that builds everything including iinstallers and maybe even deploys has saved me countless times, there is nothing more embarressing than releasing a product only for human error to have caused it not to install.  CI removes human error.