# Concepts that surprised you when you read SICP?

Tags: sicp

SICP - "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"

Explanation for the same would be nice

Can some one explain about **Metalinguistic Abstraction**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read
the book i am mentioning is in third

Comment: How the hell do you put a bounty on a subjective question? Especially one that is so closely related to personal experience?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing?

Comment: there were no answers for this question without bounty

Comment: So change the question then. This is like awarding a gold medal to the swimmer with the best personal training story - nice to read, but not worthy of a medal.

Comment: 23 hours to go,  you should pick the answer so the bounty doesn't get lost in the system.

Comment: Stack Overflow is explicitly focused on *narrow* questions about *specific* problems with *objective* answers. SICP is a great book, but this is entirely off-topic here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SICP really drove home the point that it is possible to look at code and data as the same thing.

I understood this before when thinking about universal Turing machines (the input to a UTM is just a  representation of a program) or the von Neumann architecture (where a single storage structure holds both code and data), but SICP made the idea much more clear.  Scheme (Lisp) helped here, as the syntax for a program is exactly the same as the syntax for lists in general, namely S-expressions.

Once you have the "equivalence" of code and data, suddenly a lot of things become easy.  For example, you can write programs that have different evaluation methods (lazy, nondeterministic, *etc*).  Previously, I might have thought that this would require an extension to the programming language; in reality, I can just add it on to the language myself, thus allowing the core language to be minimal.  As another example, you can similarly implement an object-oriented framework; again, this is something I might have naively thought would require modifying the language.

Incidentally, one thing I wish SICP had mentioned more: types.  Type checking at *compilation* time is an amazing thing.  The SICP implementation of object-oriented programming did not have this benefit.

Comment: Heh… writing in assembly is what made me look at code and data as the same thing. I still miss it, sometimes — rewriting jumps may not have been the most *clear* way to both store and handle program state, but it was certainly *concise*. :-)

Answer (score 9):

I didn't read that book yet, I have only looked at the video courses, but it taught me a lot. Functions as first class citizens was mind blowing for me. Executing a "variable" was something very new to me. After watching those videos the way I now see JavaScript and programming in general has greatly changed.

Oh, I think I've lied, the thing that really struck me was that + was a function.

Comment: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/
great material!

Answer (score 5):

The one that I thought was really cool was [streams](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html) with delayed evaluation. The one about generating primes was something I thought was really neat. Like a "PEZ" dispenser that magically dispenses the next prime in the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most surprising thing about SICP is to see how few primitives are actually required to make a Turing complete language--almost anything can be built from almost nothing.

Since we are discussing SICP, I'll put in my standard plug for the video lectures at http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/, which are the best Introduction to Computer Science you could hope to get in 20 hours.

Answer (score 4):

One example of "the data and the code are the same thing" from A. Rex's answer got me in a very deep way.

When I was taught Lisp back in Russia, our teachers told us that the language was about lists: car, cdr, cons. What really amazed me was the fact that you don't need those functions at all - you can write your own, given closures. So, Lisp is not about lists after all! That was a big surprise.

Comment: I loved that realization, too.

Answer (score 3):

A concept I was completely unfamiliar with was the idea of [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine), i.e. having two functions doing complementary work and having the program flow control alternate between them.

Answer (score 2):

I was still in high school when I read SICP, and I had focused on the first and second chapters. For me at the time, I liked that you could express all those mathematical ideas in code, and have the computer do most of the dirty work.

When I was tutoring SICP, I got impressed by different aspects. For one, the conundrum that data and code are really the same thing, because code is executable data. The chapter on metalinguistic abstractions is mind-boggling to many and has many take-home messages. The first is that all the rules are arbitrary. This bothers some students, specially those who are physicists at heart. I think the beauty is not in the rules themselves, but in studying the consequence of the rules. A one-line change in code can mean the difference between lexical scoping and dynamic scoping.

Today, though SICP is still fun and insightful to many, I do understand that it's becoming dated. For one, it doesn't teach debugging skills and tools (I include type systems in there), which is essential for working in today's gigantic systems.

Answer (score 2):

I was most surprised of how easy it is to implement languages. That one could write interpreter for Scheme onto a blackboard.

Answer (score 1):

I felt Recursion in different sense after reading some of the chapters of SICP

Answer (score 1):

I am right now on Section "Sequences as Conventional Interfaces" and have found the concept of procedures as first class citizens quite fascinating. Also, the application of recursion is something I have never seen in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Closures.

Coming from a primarily imperative background (Java, C#, etc. -- I only read SICP a year or so ago for the first time, and am re-reading it now), thinking in functional terms was a big revelation for me; it totally changed the way I think about my work today.

Answer (score 0):

I read most part of the book (without exercise). What I have learned is how to abstract the real world at a specific level, and how to implement a language.

Each chapter has ideas surprise me:

The first two chapters show me two ways of abstracting the real world: abstraction with the procedure, and abstraction with data.

Chapter 3 introduces time in the real world. That results in states. We try assignment, which raises problems. Then we try streams.

Chapter 4 is about metalinguistic abstraction, in other words, we implement a new language by constructing an evaluator, which determines the meaning of expressions.

Since the evaluator in Chapter 4 is itself a Lisp program, it inherits the control structure of the underlying Lisp system.  So in Chapter 5, we dive into the step-by-step operation of a real computer with the help of an abstract model, register machine.

Thanks.