# Why am I getting the wrong signature for the Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: python, hmac, amazon-product-api

I'm following the directions on the API documentation precisely, and after some frustration I finally put together something directly from their examples on http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/rest-signature.html

I've tried this python script on a few machines and have gotten the same result on all of them.

```
import hmac
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha256

secret_key = '1234567890'

to_sign = """GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06"""

print b64encode(hmac.new(secret_key, to_sign, sha256).digest())
```

The instructions say that the signature using this request, and this key, is `Nace+U3Az4OhN7tISqgs1vdLBHBEijWcBeCqL5xN9xg=` but I get `O6UTkH+m4zAQUvB+WXUZJeA8bZcKAdkc4crKgHtbc6s=`

(Before anyone says anything: The example page displays the requests wrapped at 65 characters; I've already tried it. This doesn't provide a solution, and is not stated in the instructions for signature creation.)

---

EDIT: I found the answer, see below.

Comment: FYI to others: amazon's JS implementation works as of sep 2013 and is useful for troubleshooting. http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, look at that...  The docs were wrong.

I stumbled on an old (nearly) duplicate of this question: [Calculating a SHA hash with a string + secret key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306550/calculating-a-sha-hash-with-a-string-secret-key-in-python)

It looks like the `AWSAccessKeyId` value changed from `00000000000000000000` to `AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE` in the example requests page.

Updating this in the script prints the expected key, `Nace+U3Az4OhN7tISqgs1vdLBHBEijWcBeCqL5xN9xg=`

```
import hmac
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha256

secret_key = '1234567890'

to_sign = """GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
AWSAccessKeyId=00000000000000000000&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06"""

print b64encode(hmac.new(secret_key, to_sign, sha256).digest())
```

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the Bottlenose library, https://github.com/dlo/bottlenose, I have found that it makes dealing with AWS Product API much more friendly.

Comment: Man, I was looking everywhere today for a wrapper for the API - I ended up just writing my own, and the only problem I was having was with the signature.  Until I found the mysterious inconsistent change on the example page I thought that my signature creation was incorrect.  Turns out that my real problem was that I forgot the "Z" on the end of the timestamp.