# python password generator for django

Tags: python, django

How can I manually generate password for django? For example, in other application, but using  the same database as django .For username 'admin'  password like this

```
pbkdf2_sha256$10000$T0BzrDwfZSrI$pSgvDEam9V9jcdYpYDVkYMMwtSnRrFdf6Aqow82Tjr8=
```

Answer (score 15):

I think this maybe what you are looking for :

[Manually managing a user’s password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers)

> **make_password(password[, salt, hashers])**
>
> Creates a hashed password in
>   the format used by this application. It takes one mandatory argument:
>   the password in plain-text. Optionally, you can provide a salt and a
>   hashing algorithm to use, if you don’t want to use the defaults (first
>   entry of PASSWORD_HASHERS setting). Currently supported algorithms
>   are: 'pbkdf2_sha256', 'pbkdf2_sha1', 'bcrypt_sha256' (see Using bcrypt
>   with Django), 'bcrypt', 'sha1', 'md5', 'unsalted_md5' (only for
>   backward compatibility) and 'crypt' if you have the crypt library
>   installed. If the password argument is None, an unusable password is
>   returned (a one that will be never accepted by check_password()).

---

> I want write function for using without django

Well luckily Django is open source, so you can go and take what you need. [The functions source is visible here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/68540fe4df44492571bc610a0a043d3d02b3d320/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L65).

Comment: thanks, but this methods used with django application. I want write function for using without django, something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306550/calculating-a-sha-hash-with-a-string-secret-key-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The most common (**not safest**) algorithm for hashing is `md5`. Extracting a few ideas from Django's password system can be this code:

```
import hashlib

def make_password(password):
    assert password
    hash = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
    return hash

def check_password(hash, password):
    """Generates the hash for a password and compares it."""
    generated_hash = make_password(password)
    return hash == generated_hash


>>> hash = make_password('hello123')
>>> hash
'f30aa7a662c728b7407c54ae6bfd27d1'
>>> check_password(hash, 'hello123')
True
>>> check_password(hash, 'Hello123')
False
```

Use `make_password` to generate a hash and `check_password` to check if the entered password is the same as the stored one.

As @Emil pointed out, Django supports multiple password hashers such as pbkdf2_sha256 and pbkdf2_sha1, storing the string as a 3-fold value separated by `$`: `algorithm$salt$hash`.  `salt` is a randomly generated string to prevent same password from repeating in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working Node script, maybe it can help someone out there:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const djangoIterations = 260000; //Default for Django 3.2 (its increased to 480000 for new django versions)

function generateSalt(length) {
  return crypto.randomBytes(length).toString('base64');
}

function djangoHash(password, iterations = djangoIterations, salt = generateSalt(12)) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const keylen = 32;
    const digest = 'sha256';
    console.log(`Hashing password with ${iterations} iterations`);
    console.log(`Salt: ${salt}`);
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, (err, derivedKey) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve({
        algorithm: 'pbkdf2_sha256',
        iterations: iterations,
        salt: salt,
        hash: derivedKey.toString('base64'),
      });
    });
  });
}

djangoHash('my_password').then(({algorithm, iterations, salt, hash}) => {
  console.log(`Hash ${hash}`);
  const fullHash = `${algorithm}$${iterations}$${salt}$${hash}`;
  console.log(fullHash);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Cheers!