# SecretHash: Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, boto3

I'm using boto3 for connect Amazon Cognito. I'm trying to use sign_up method; however, there is a parameter called SecretHash which I cannot understand how it is generated.

The original documentation about SecretHash:

> SecretHash (string) -- A keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC)
>   calculated using the secret key of a user pool client and username
>   plus the client ID in the message.

I'm getting error below, if I don't put SecretHash parameter.

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the SignUp operation: Unable to
>   verify secret hash for client xxx

Answer (score 10):

Don't know if this helps, but if you're using the JavaScript SDK, in the Setup part 1, it states:

**Create an app for your user pool. Note that the generate client secret box must be unchecked because the JavaScript SDK doesn't support apps that have a client secret.**

I created another app without generating a client secret key and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I just got off support with AWS regarding this question. Here is what i was told:

AWS REP: let me start from the begnining

AWS REP: the secretHash is not 100% stable

AWS REP: in order to call the function

AWS REP: the secretHash has to be ommited

AWS REP: so, you need to call it without secretHash

AWS REP: but.....

AWS REP: if you have configured your app with secret/security setting

AWS REP: cognito will not be happy if there is no secret hash

AWS REP: so you need to use a different app key

AWS REP: that was confiured without that setting

*The rep was not sure about the algorithm that should be used and has opened a case to get the documentation updated.*

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me :

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64 

def signup( username, password, email, phone):
  msg=username + CLIENTID
  dig = hmac.new(str(CLIENTSECRET).encode('utf-8'), 
  msg=str(msg).encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
  d2 = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()
  dig = d2
  resp = pool.sign_up(
    ClientId=CLIENTID,
    SecretHash=str(dig),
    Username=username,
    Password=password,
    UserAttributes=[
            { 'Name': 'email', 'Value': email},
            { 'Name': 'phone_number', 'Value': phone}
    ])
```

This was after trying all permutations of inputs to the secret and message parts.   The CLIENTID is from AWS User Pools 'App clients' -> 'App client id'.  The CLIENTSECRET is from AWS User Pools 'App client' -> 'App client secret'.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This example shows how you could generate HMAC with SHA256 hash algorithm in python using the hmac libraries. 
[Calculating a SHA hash with a string + secret key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306550/calculating-a-sha-hash-with-a-string-secret-key-in-python)

In this case the secret for HMAC will be your 'client secret'. And the message will be utf8 bytes of (username+clientId).

You only need to provide secretHash if your client has been generated with the secret otherwise secret hash can be committed in the call.

Also I would recommended you tot explore Cognito UserPools with our client side SDKs :javascript, android or IOS. As the SDKs handle the generation of secret hash for you.

Comment: when I try to omit it by not sending this parameter, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: You need to generate a new app client which does not require a secret by unchecking the "Generate client secret" box. Then you can omit this parameter for the new client.