# AWS Cognito Unable to verify secret hash for client

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

When I try to `authenticateUser` I get

`Error: Unable to verify secret hash for client <CLIENT_ID_HERE>`

Whats wrong? My code below:

```
import {
  Config,
  CognitoIdentityCredentials
} from "aws-sdk"
import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUserAttribute,
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js"

Config.region = "ap-northeast-2"

var userpool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: "ap-northeast-2_QosOiWMkd",
  ClientId: "1bd6s9mv98bo2lucen2vesbqls"
})

var userData = {
  Username: "jiewmeng@gmail.com",
  Pool: userpool
}

var authData = new AuthenticationDetails({
  Username: "jiewmeng@gmail.com",
  Password: "P@$$w0rd"
})

var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData)
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authData, {
  onSuccess: function (result) {
    console.log("authenticated with", result)
  },
  onFailure: function (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})
```

On AWS, Client secret is already disabled

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript does not support Apps with client secret. This is stated in the [SDK documentation](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js#user-content-configuration):

> When creating the App, the generate client secret box must be
>   unchecked because the JavaScript SDK doesn't support apps that have a
>   client secret.

It looks like you are going to have to re-configure your app.

Comment: But from the image I posted, client secret is already disabled?

Comment: I found that you are correct, strangely, today when I checked again theres a client secret ... not sure if takes awhile to show or something ...

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66819267/5600195

Comment: oh boy....here we go again...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass secret_hash along with the adminAuthInitiate Request. And to calculate the secret hash you can use the following method:

```
public static String calculateSecretHash(String userPoolClientId, String userPoolClientSecret, String userName) {
final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
                userPoolClientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
            mac.init(signingKey);
            mac.update(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(userPoolClientId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawHmac);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while calculating ");
        }
    }
```

How to Pass Secret_Hash

```
Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>(2);
authParams.put("USERNAME", <username>);
authParams.put("PASSWORD", <password>);
                    authParams.put("SECRET_HASH", calculateSecretHash(cognitoClientId, cognitoClientSecret, <username>));
                    AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                            .withClientId(userPool.getClientId()).withUserPoolId(userPool.getUserPoolId())
                            .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH).withAuthParameters(authParams);
                    AdminInitiateAuthResult result = cognito.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);
                    auth = result.getAuthenticationResult();
```