# Unable to sign up using awscli, getting NotAuthorizedException exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli, serverless

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-cognito-test-user.html) to learn about serverless. When i issued following command, I got error

```
aws cognito-idp sign-up \
  --region us-east-2 \
  --client-id 6gj*********************bu \
  --username admin@example.com \
  --password Passw0rd!

An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the SignUp operation: Unable to verify secret hash for client 6gj*********************bu
```

So far i have tried following things but nothing worked

1. I have made sure the region i am using in the command is the correct one
2. I have made sure that `aws configure` is set to correct region (though it doesn't make sense since i am explicitly putting region in the command)
3. Created new app in cognito pool. ACtually not only created new app, i created a new AWS account to test it out and still getting same issue
4. I have also tried email and password in single-quotes. and in other combination i tried just the password in single-quotes. in both cases, got the same error

P.S: I am running this command from `iTerm2` installed on my mac. I have `oh-my-zsh` configured on it.

Comment: Could it be that your password is being mangled by shell interpolation?  Use `--password 'Passw0rd!'`.

Comment: just tried with 2 different combination. in one i have tried with both email and password in quotes. and in other combination i tried your suggested approach. it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to verify secret hash for client in Amazon Cognito Userpools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438879/unable-to-verify-secret-hash-for-client-in-amazon-cognito-userpools)