# How to generate a hash SHA256 for POST in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256, hmac

I have the need to POST a request to a service that requires a hash SHA256 signature for autentication.
I have both "app_id" and "app_secret" used to generate the hash during the process.

I have tried to do it, but receiving an invalid signature from the service provider when trying to POST a request.

From the provider instructions, I need to:

**1.** Create a MAC string that will contain all request data. This should be the elements:

`AppId + HTTP Method + URI + UNIX Timestamp + Nonce (unique string for each request) + base64 string from payload md5`

**2.** Generate the SHA256 hash from the string in point 1, using the provided AppSecret.
**3.** The final authentication signature will be composed of the following elements:

`[ApiKey AppId:hash:nonce:timestamp]`

What I have done so far:

```
app_id = 'my_app_id'
app_secret = 'my_app_secret'
providerURL = 'https://the_provider_url'

#code for calling the POST method
def publish_data(number, date, status):
    endPointUrl = providerURL + "/v1/posting"
    
    #just for testing purposes
    number = '123456789'
    date = None #opcional
    status = 'valid'
    
    payload = "?number={}&date={}&status={}".format(str(number), str(date), str(status))
    strHash = hmac_generator(endPointUrl, 'POST', payload)
    request_headers = {'Authorization': "ApiKey " + strHash, 
                       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                       }
    response = requests.post(endPointUrl, headers=request_headers)
    print('RESPONSE:', response.text)
```

```
#code for generating the hash
def hmac_generator(uri, method, body=None):
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    nonce = str(uuid.uuid4())

    content = ""
    if body is not None:
        body_md5 = hashlib.md5(body.encode('utf-8')).digest()
        content = base64.b64encode(body_md5).decode('utf-8')
    
    #Generate the based64 MAC 
    #AppId + HTTP Method + URI + UNIX Timestamp + Nonce + base64 string from payload md5
    
    message = app_id + method + uri + str(timestamp) + nonce + content
    message_bytes = message.encode('utf-8')
    
    #Generate the SHA256 hash
    signature = hmac.new(app_secret, msg=message_bytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    hashed = base64.b64encode(signature).decode('utf-8')

    return "{}:{}:{}:{}".format(app_id, hashed, nonce, timestamp)
```

I believe it is something related to "payload" because when I try to use a GET method using the same approach, it is working fine.

Code below:

```
#This method does not use payload
def get_details(number):
    number = 'an existing number'
    strUrl = endPointUrl + "/getdetails/" + str(number)
    strHash = self.hmac_generator(strUrl, 'GET', None)
    request_headers = {
                    'Authorization': "ApiKey " + strHash, 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                       }
    response = requests.get(strUrl, headers=request_headers)
    return response
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

I have tried to create some code as per the original question.
When trying to POST, I am getting an "invalid signature" error.
When I try to GET, everything runs fine.

Comment: I'm not really sure but the `?` at the beginning of your payload seems weird. Maybe try removing that.

Comment: did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306550/calculating-a-sha-hash-with-a-string-secret-key-in-python

Comment: @tobifasc, thank you. Removed and problem remains the same. I still think is something related with the payload (content), because the GET methot works since it uses no payload...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I was lost sending the "payload" only in the "hmac_generator" method:

```
strHash = hmac_generator(endPointUrl, 'POST', payload)
```

...and forgot to include it in the requests:

Old code:

```
response = requests.post(endPointUrl, headers=request_headers)
```

Fixed code:

```
response = requests.post(strUrl, headers=request_headers, data=payload)
```

Problem was the payload not being sent to response.

Thank you