# What are some good 'software design' books / resources that are currently recommended?

Tags: software-design

I recently applied to several full time positions among some of the tech giants, and this was among some of the feedback I received.

I know what good coding practice generally entails, but am not so sure on largescale software design that mixes not only creativity but also a sharp technical focus.

What do you guys recommend?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406/what-development-book-made-the-most-impact-on-you-as-a-developer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158769/best-books-to-learn-about-design.

Comment: Thanks for the links, can't delete due to upvoted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code Complete is always a winner.

Answer (score 2):

[The Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer)