# How do I learn about programming fundamentals?

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in programming. I have a large piece of code. I want to break it up into functions, return values, pass those values to another function. I want to be an expert in doing this. Give me suggestions on where to study or how to be an expertise on these simple fundamentals. When will I use pointers in the functions and all this?

Comment: perl is the language i am using nw

Comment: "Learning Perl" is a good book with exercises.

Comment: Beginning perl is free online, after that I recommend reading Perl Best Practices

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read?tab=votes) -- start at the top of the books recommended there and work your way down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner,

Best way to learn **Perl** is to read standard book e.g.; **[Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271)** by the inventor itself.

This book helps you to understand lot of things like

- **Subroutines**
- **Data structures**
- **References** etc etc.

Comment: For a beginner, reading [*Learning Perl* (5th edition)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113/) beforehand is advisable.

Comment: @daxim: That's true, agreed but if we know the basic of programming, then we can also read Programming Perl too.Thanks