# Learning simple programming conventions

Tags: conventions, idioms

Where can I learn more about simple programming conventions and design patterns?

When I say simple I mean which is the preferred way of writing the following equivalent functions:

```
function() {
  if (condition) {
    # condition wraps the entire function
  }
}
```

or

```
function() {
  if (!condition) {
    return;
  }

  # rest of the function
}
```

There's also this:

```
function() {
  $return_val = 'foo';

  if (condition) {
    $return_val = 'bar';
  }

  return $return_val;
}
```

vs this:

```
function() {
  if (condition) {
    return 'bar';
  }

  return 'foo';
}
```

Are these arbitrary differences or is are there established idioms for such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code complete. Also read this list of books [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Answer (score 0):

At most places there will either be explicit ie written down and expected or implicit ie copied so often you think it is a standard standards.  Over time most people develop there own preferred style that is a mixture of there personality and experience.

Answer (score -1):

> Are these arbitrary differences

Yes.

> are there established idioms for such things?

No.

Go to a design review.  Listen to the arguments over this kind of thing.