# What Are The Motivations And Benefits Of Refactoring?

Tags: refactoring

Why do we do refactoring? What are the benefits of refactoring? What problems can be avoided by performing refactoring the code of a software tool?

Comment: Why do we clean up our rooms frequently?

Comment: @Pekka - I don't. I mean, it's just gonna get dirty again, duh.

Comment: @Pekka, because some of us don't live with our moms ;)

Comment: There are plenty of resources.  Such as [A book on refactoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read/13332#13332)...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood what refactoring is. Delete if you'd like.

Comment: See [What is the best way to explain refactoring to non-technical people?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138823/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-refactoring-to-non-technical-people)

Comment: @Pekka, you clean your room frequently?

Comment: Why do people ask stupid homework or test questions on SO?

Comment: @Raj: You can delete it yourself. I guess.

Comment: @Raj, I think this is a perfectly legitimate question.  I think some people just like to downvote to feel superior.

Comment: @Abe ummm... Well, not as often as I should. :)

Comment: @Abe the question *is* legitimate, but it is put in a way that *sounds* like somebody got tasked with doing some research (especially the "what problems can be avoided" bit), and is looking to "outsource" that research to us instead of reading the relevant Wikipedia article. That is sometimes met by some indignation, rightly in my mind.

Comment: @Pekka, it does sound like homework.  I just don't get why some of those questions get polite suggestions to add the homework tag and others others get rude comments from people like @DVK and downvotes...  @Raj, doesn't appear to have much experience on SO and instead of trying to help him along everyone blew him out of the water.

Comment: @Abe: The difference is that sometimes these homework questions - even though they are obviously homework - are asked *after the OP has made some research or tried to implement it himself*. Questions which obviously weren't researched on are often punished with downvotes and unkind comments...

Comment: @Raj, is this a homework/test question?  If so please add the "homework" tag to your question.  As you may have gathered from the negative reception, the SO community prefers that you do SOME research on your own before coming here with your questions.  You will get a much better response in the future if you do this.

Comment: This was no homework or test question. I am far far out of college and school. However fundamental and obvious the question may have been I wanted others perspective on it. One thing is clear though: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask questions and get helpful responses at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While developing an application it often happens that your goals change. Especially if a non-technical person is your client it often happens that through his bad description you are going to modify the code again and again.

At some point everything will get really messy and needs cleanup - that's refactoring.