# Alternative to Code Complete 2nd Edition

Tags: language-agnostic

I've looked at [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) to find some books to read. The books are needed for my train trip each day to/from work and having a book on 960 pages is just a bit over kill in my opinion. Therefore i'm looking for an alternative to code complete which is just a bit smaller and maybe something like 2-300 pages.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: "Code Complete" is just right. If you find it too weighty for carrying it on the train, split it in two halves by page 460.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer) - pragmatic *and* light.

Comment: And, dare I say it, genuinely valuable. I'll leave it at that.