# Literature suggestions for best practices / good coding techniques

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

I am a mid level developer. Currently I work in C# ASP.NET but I have worked in PHP, classic ASP, and a tiny bit in Java (would like to get more into this in the future). I am looking for a few suggestions on good books to help me continue growing in my coding techniques.

Basically a book with lots of best practices, coding tricks, rarely used but very useful features and operators (e.g. the ?? operator), stuff like that. I am NOT looking for a book to teach me a specific language. I don't particularly care about what language the code samples are in but C or Java would probably be best. The suggestions don't need to be limited to pure code objects either. Books with information about database connection management ect. would be good.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Practically a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Required reading: [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone. I'll choose this one as the accepted because it's the first on the list and I'm reading it now :)

Answer (score 2):

The first book that comes to mind for me is [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com).  It's fantastic.  Absolutely required reading for a serious developer.

If by rarely used stuff, you think Bitwise operations, [Hacker's Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654) is supposed to be really well regarded.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't Make Me Think](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html) is a solid read.  No real coding tricks, but it delivers good usability related best practices.

Answer (score 2):

[The Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) is an excellent language-agnostic guide to becoming a better programmer.

Answer (score 2):

- [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880)
- [The Art of Computer Programming](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) because [Knuth is my homeboy](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ioerror/3014911710/)

More Recent

- [The Productive Programmer](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596519544)
- [Masterminds of Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596515171)

Answer (score 1):

For your java Skills:

- [Effective Java (2. Edition)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

and in general

- [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/product-reviews/0132350882)

I strongly recommend to read Effective Java **before** reading Clean Code. -- Because it will make you more sensitive for a few (I personal belive not so optimal) code changes suggested in clean code.