# How to organize a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

For the first time I'm creating a quite complex Rails app.

I'd like to know what's the best way to organize that app by folders. Until now, I'd do everything under one app (all the models, controllers, etC) but reading some open source code I realize that they put everything under different apps.

Like for example Spree Commerce. They have a general folder and inside that they have different apps (API, core, admin, etc). How is that done and is that the best way to do it?

I'd like to get pointed to the best way to do it (a book, blog, anything) so I can understand how I can architect my app for future maintenance.

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an aside I think the title of your question is a little confusing.  Rails, by using convention over configuration, defines 'how to organise a Rails app'.  I think your question is rather about how to *architect* your application as opposed to anything Rails-specific.  Maybe tweak the title?

That aside, without knowing any more detail about your project it's a tricky question to answer, but I'll give it a go.

All applications should start off simple, if you believe (like I do) that you should start by building [the simplest thing that could possibly work](http://c2.com/xp/DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork.html). Given this, since you're using Rails, then in all likelihood the simplest thing would be to structure your app as a vanilla Rails 3 application.  This will probably (I say 'probably' because I don't know any specifics about the app) allow you to get a beta version of your app up and running pretty quickly without worrying about complexities which at this stage in the development of your project are not a problem.

If you need to create an XML or JSON-based API then Rails makes this [really easy](http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/) using the standard framework, which will allow you to spend more time thinking about the *API design* than how to code it, and it's the API design which is the most important thing to get right in the first instance.

Similarly, your Admin site can be part of the same app just in a different namespace.  If you find later down the line that you want it as a separate app, you can do this (maybe you could use the awesome API you designed to facilitate this), but why bother designing it with this added complexity (and hence extended development time) in the first place if you don't have a good reason for doing so?

Once you have your app up and running and people are starting to use it, you start to get a picture of where the bottlenecks are and where the design could be improved.  At this stage, if there's a need, you can start to move parts of the app to scalable solutions, such as running your API as a standalone service, introducing caching, changing data stores and other improvements and optimisations.

Even if your app is as wildly successful (and I hope it is!) then re-architecting your application whist continuing to run the existing service is still entirely possible, as Twitter have proved.  Just stick to [Knuth's statement](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and you'll be alright.

Regarding reading material, that's a tricky one.  For me a lot of the XP and agile development classics taught me a huge amount about how to approach program and app design.  I'd also check [this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read/) for book inspiration.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Spree uses Rails' [Railties](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) ([Rails::Engines](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)). Railties are introduced in Rails 3 to make it more modular and easy to extend. Rails 3 itself is a collection of Railties (ActiveSupport, ActiveModel, ActiveRecord, etc.).

If you are developing a complex app I would suggest spending some time planing its' architecture. Designing a complex app without any initial planning would definitely end with a maintenance nightmare down the road. It also introduces a huge learning curve for the new team members, slow down your new feature introduction and of course, frustration.

Anyway, don't over optimize, but don't forget to design your architecture for your needs.

Comment: this is the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I will create very complex projects as one app. I have reason to believe that Spree and Radiant build under seperate apps so that under the pretense of their open source communities, contributors can contribute code easily without tampering with the core data, and the core workings of the application.

Otherwise, you should be alright just building it as one app. Just keep it neat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what have kept me sane for several years of RoR development:

1. I use Rails Engines, but keep them in same codebase as the main app. Here is good starter for modular Rails app:
   https://github.com/shageman/the_next_big_thing
2. Wherever I can I try to reduce coupling and use composition to make things easily testable, reusable and maintainable. This helps to eventually extract module or engine as separate gem. Composition is done by routes (mounting), directory overlaying (assets), dependency injection or configuration.
3. If I don't need to re-use an engine I put it in the same code base as the main app which is single deployment unit. Thanks to that I don't need to switch between projects in my IDE. While in development environment any changes to the engine code are instantly picked up by Rails reload mechanism.