# Instance method called from class method causes app to crash

Tags: objective-c

I have this code where I am attempting to create a database;  I'm getting a warning (which is causing the crash) about "instance variable 'db' accessed in a class method".  Being a newbie, I don't know how to fix it (crash occurs on line 57).  Help is appreciated.  :D

[image: the .m file]

This is the .h file:
[image: the .h file]

Comment: You should paste code inline. Indent by 4 spaces to indicate that it's code.

Comment: OK... will do in the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkIfDatabaseExist` is a class method (you marked it with `+`). This method belongs to class itself no to instances of this class. `db` is instance variable so class method doesn't have access to it. Make `checkIfDatabaseExist` instance method

```
- (void)checkIfDatabaseExists { ... }
```

Comment: On this code (where I call 'checkIfDatabaseExists', I'm getting a warning: SQLiteDB may not respond to +sharedSQLiteDB.  How do I fix that?
`myDB = [SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB];  //  instantiate SQLiteDB
 [SQLiteDB checkIfDatabaseExists];  //  see if the database exists`

Comment: It's because there is no `sharedSQLiteDB` in your class interface. Just declare this method in interface part of `SQLiteDB` like `+ (SQLiteDB *)sharedSQLiteDB;` and this warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks HoHo... did that, but still getting a SIGABRT (see http://imgur.com/sCz1Q).

Comment: Since you've made `checkIfDatabaseExists` an instance method you have to send `checkIfDatabaseExists` message to instances - for example to object returned to you by `[SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB]`

Comment: I really recommend you to read 'The Objective-C Programming Language' (you can find it in 'Developer Documentation' section of Help menu). Reading this will repay very soon

Comment: Thanks, HoHa... I have bought several books, none of which help very much... I'm a C# programmer, usually using Monotouch, but for this app, I can't.  Struggling with Obj-C.  Today I purchased "Cocoa in a Nutshell", which I think will help.  Thanks for your time and advice, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't know C language I highly recommend to read "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. It's in Top-10 in this thread about most influential books - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read. C is really important language to know and not only because it's a subset of Objective-C Good luck!

Comment: Hoha... I know C, C++, C# and a few other languages... I'm just having a hard time getting my hands around Objective-C... if I knew Smalltalk (I think that's where some of the Obj-C design came from), I could probably figure it out... but right now, I'm struggling with it... the light will eventually turn on, just hope it's before I die! :D