# Good language to implement for senior project?

Tags: language-design, compiler-construction

Its my last semester of college and I have to do a big presentation in December.  I plan on designing a small language that not only works, but also has some nifty features to go with it.  Does anyone have any interesting syntax ideas or features that would impress my professors?

Note: I do not want to just copy a language and reimplement it.  Im looking to do a little research and try some new ideas out.

Comment: If this is your last semester of your course, should you be coming up with ideas? Have you thought of asking your professors???

Comment: Given the amount of time you have left to do this, I would recommend getting a very simple language working and then when you have time left start adding on more "advanced" features.

Comment: Syntax does not matter at all, you'd better stay away from having any syntax for as long as possible, otherwise it could be quite distractive. And if you're seeking a neat semantics for your language, try to climb the lambda cube as far as you can, most of the interesting stuff nowadays is in type systems. Implement your own little Turing-complete dependent type system for a  non-Turing-complete language, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I might not be able to answer your question directly, I am sure this will give you some insights from my own experience - given, for a final year project I also attempted my own scripting language (in C++) - although I am aware you're attempting a compiler so there might not be similarities. Please learn from my mistakes.

From experience:

1. What you imagine the scripting language will do (you type in a command, does something nifty like it fixes windows or something) and what it actually does (you type in a command, but minutes later it crashes) can often be two different things. Keep it realistic.
2. Aside from the brain imagining this fantastic finished product (with no inbetween), it also has a tendency of deluding itself on it's own capabilities (like 'other programmers made that mistake but I won't!'). Chances are you do make the same mistakes, or if not the same, different mistakes.
3. The brain has a poor ability to assess time required (if it's thinking 'it's just a hack job that'll take a month' - think again), and time it thinks is required should be multiplied between 5 to 10 times (if not more) to get an accurate idea of real scope needed. Keep to the lengthy end of the scope - worse-case scenario.
4. Unexpected pitfalls. Like 'how do I implement multi-precedented logic statements' and 'it's taking longer than I expected (see 3.)'. Be willing to give up complicated matters.
5. Design. Don't just look for ideas, think about whether or not it's a viable project, and look at how you're going to implement the groundwork before jumping to the complicated stuff (see 1.). Laying the groundwork early on can save you time. And don't forget design documents.
6. Research. Chances are that function you plan to write out, has already been written before somewhere. Research for it. This will save you time. Do not reinvent the wheel and do not be concerned about efficiency (university is about learning).
7. As one commenter said, start simple, get it working, then expand.

Best way to develop useful ideas, is to see what really bothers you about a certain task or certain scripting languages, and build it so you can eliminate or minimise that task. For example, I got annoyed by having to keep downloading files from a website and sorting it manually into specific folders - so I built a program to do that for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have a crazy idea.

There are compilers that compile compilers.   This is fun enough by itself.
You can implement one in the MetaII style (read this other SO answer:
[Are there any "fun" ways to learn about Languages, Grammars, Parsing and Compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739133/are-there-any-fun-ways-to-learn-about-languages-grammars-parsing-and-compiler/5739338#5739338))

What makes this doable for a student project is that the MetaII compiler is remarkably small, and
the technical paper (read the other answer) has everything you need in 10 pages
except some sweat, which you supply.  And this fits
well in the time frame you have available  (which is frankly pretty short for as student
to just sit down and whack out a compiler by himself).

MetaII's own description of itself is remarkably terse: only some 50 lines(!).

And since it can compile itself, it can compile *enhanced* versions of itself... so 
you can use it to bootstrap much more complicated compilers.  Normally, that's the
direction most people want to take it, since MetaII by itself is fairly simple.

Here's the crazy idea:  You can also use it to compile *less* capable versions of itself.
The question is, how much can you take out, and still be able to climb back up the
metacompiler ladder?   How small a compiler can you build that is still bootstrappable?

I know for a fact that MetaII has 2 items are removable, since I've done
this in the long distant past.  I'm not going to tell you what they are becuase
that spoils the discovery process.    But its good in a student project to take
on something that is already known to be doable, so you don't go down alleys
that have real dead ends.

One of the people I'm knew long ago apparantly tried to do this seriously.  His goal was to reduce this to a very short string of characters... think of this as "compiler DNA".

Answer (score 0):

Don't go general-purpose for such a small project. Find a niche where you would like to be able to program a solution to an everyday problem. Off the top of my head, how about a constraint language for window placement in your X11 window manager of choice?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to have some fun, then you should try and create your own 'esoteric language'. 'Brainf**k' has kinda achieved meme status in the community (If I'm not wrong)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language