# breaking up a monolithic project

Tags: c#, wpf, project-management

I am about to break a monolithic WPF/C# application into manageable modules. Please let me know what are the points i need to remember before breaking the software. Any tools that would be handy,etc.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

JOhn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your tool set there are a couple of things which generally help when analyzing a code base from an architectural or structural viewpoint.

In VS 2010 Ultimate or with a tool like nDepend you can generate dependency graphs which help you see you application's dependencies and code usage can be useful when trying to break large code into smaller api's or services.

Also unit tests and integration tests can help ensure that functionality is maintained without introducing bugs and using refactoring tools like resharper, justCode or coderush can really help to adjust your namespaces, code file physical locations and class/method signatures when dealing with a large codebases into smaller more manageable libraries and projects.

On the planning side you really need to establish the key elements of the application from a separation of concerns point of view to define the boundaries of each module.

Probably the worst thing you can do though is just launch in and start hacking the code into chunks. Mapping out a phased migration for one module at a time would be my strategy of choice.

Agree with the above comment though that the question is too broad to get any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad as there are many techniques (e.g. heavily unit testing your code) that are of help. It is probably best to read a book on that topic. I can highly recommend you Michael C. Feathers

> **[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)**

[image]

Although this book is mostly Java-centric the described techniques are generally applicable. It will definitely change the way you write and think about code and will be of help when working with existing applications.

Feathers' book is also one of the books that are most recommended in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read/3116#3116).

Answer (score 0):

To complete Mac answer on tooling such as NDepend (*Disclaimer: I am a developer of the tool NDepend*) I'd advise to read [these 2 white books](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) on how to partition your code in assemblies, layers and components. This is certainly the key to break your monolithic code base.

- [Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf) (8 pages)
- [Defining .NET Components with Namespaces](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Namespace.pdf) (7 pages)