# Enterprise design pattern online learning resource

Tags: design-patterns, wcf-ria-services, enterprise

There are numerous resources/tutorials/samples available for OO design patterns like GoF. Are there any similar resources/tutorials/samples available online for enterprise design patterns. 
I went through Martin Fowler's website but it is not for the beginnners. (Though, I am planning to buy Martin Fowler's book on Enterprise patterns.)
As a quick start can you suggest some of the online resources. Specifically I am looking for patterns used in WCF RIA services.

Thank you.

Comment: I found this 300+ page documentation on Enterprise Solution Patterns
Using Microsoft .NET [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=3C81C38E-ABFC-484F-A076-CF99B3485754&displaylang=en][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enterprise library might be useful for you. It's an open source set of enterprise building blocks:

http://entlib.codeplex.com/

Or you can buy this, Design Pattern Framework 4: http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx

"An easy-to-follow guide for .NET 4.0 architects building applications with Design Patterns."

Both I find very useful. The latter link is more beginner friendly. I also recommend buying the book "Head First Design Patterns", because that will complement the material of the Design Pattern Framework (and is one of the most influential programming books [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read))

Comment: I have read & reread Head First design patterns. Now I want to understand how design patterns at enterprise level solve the problem. Also, I am planning to use WCF RIA service in one of the projects. Visual studio has created so many files that I am becoming clueless how things work under the hood of WCF RIA Services.

Comment: @Sandeep G B: **Design Pattern Framework 4** includes examples that are based on design patterns including an E-commerce Silverlight Application with MVVM, RIA Services, MEF. I found the source code to be clear and if you just use the application with the debugger on, you wil see the concepts in action.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I did write an [article for MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Ee336308.aspx) on this very topic. In it, I discuss how to evolve your application to support more advance patterns while leveraging RIA Services.