# ASP.net/C# books to create realtime applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I want to create realtime applications using ASP.Net C#

Is there any .Net books you recommend which have topics on architecting and implementing event based/message based realtime systems?

Editted:
I don't mind if it you know of a book which is based on real time web systems and is not based on .Net but created for generic purposes. I want to understand the concepts too.

I have been programming on ASP.Net for 4/5 years so anything advanced will be preferred.

Comment: There is a couple of good posts of books on stackoverflow, maybe you can find something in them. http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/797672 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711/797672

Answer (score 1):

for .net try [This](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=9469&locale=en-us) Book its good and for asp.net try [Microsoft® ASP.NET Internals](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Book.aspx?ID=13220&locale=en-us)

Comment: I wonder if I have to put a timer on my front end for it to update timely?  Can we not create push notifications in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this.
Pro ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010, Fourth Edition by Matthew MacDonald.
Check the table of content yourself to confirm whether it is useful to your need.
[Table Of Content](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225297)