# Book recommendation to improve programming solution skills

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm self taught. I'm currently doing most of my work in Rails. Sometimes I find it difficult to solve complex programming problems, as I'm sure a lot of us do. What would be a good subject or book to study to improve programming solving skills?

Is there a specific book about the matter? Maybe something like math, algebra, calculus? General computer science? A book like this http://pragprog.com/book/ahptl/pragmatic-thinking-and-learning ? General OOP?

Comment: Take a look on some of them http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/1017941

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Comment: If nothing else, the **1,440** upvotes and the amazing and interesting number of answers is worth a read!

Comment: **I know how to program**. I just want to improve my programming problem solving skills.

Comment: Yes, look at the books,a lot of them are about algorithms, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have over 20 years of programming experience, and in my experience some good ways to improve your programming skills are (not in any order of priority)

a) Solve complex programming problems

b) Revisit your solutions to see where improvements can be made (2-3 passes at least).A good book with tips to improve your programs is refactoring: [http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

c) Dr. Dobbs is an excellent site to get tips and insight:
   http://www.drdobbs.com/

e) Look at other people's code, eg. open source code so you don't
   develop a frog in the well mindset. This is a great way to learn good practices.

f) Learn to program in multiple languages (eg Java, PHP). This is also a great way to
   improve skills.

g) Try and always think 'best practices' when writing code. HTH.

Comment: In addition to learning multiple languages, in Rails it also helps to learn multiple databases.  ActiveRecord/ActiveModel's abstraction of the database sometimes hides the complexity of queries, and I find that it's often very interesting to solve the same problem when you don't have the veil of AR/AM to hide the nasty bits.

Answer (score 3):

Know your data structures and algorithms and design patterns.
Design Patterns by the gang of four comes well recommended
Head first into design patterns is also a good one.

I personally do programming puzzles I find online puzzles on codingbat.com,  pojecteuler.com, uva.onlinejudge.org and other sites you can find on google. I believe UVA has a book for training people who participate in the competition.
Also bounce around http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming and
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming

But yeah, the best way to get good at something is to do it over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of books about computers science but the best IMHO is Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Answer (score 1):

A discrete mathematics textbook, such as *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, would be beneficial.