# How do you prefer to split your multi-part program?

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, multi-project

Having a program that has several distinct *parts* is usual.By *part* I mean a graphical part that has its own windows and functionalities.(About non graphical part, I think creating a library is the preferable solution)
How do you prefer to separate them ? 
Is it better to make each of them a static library and use them in the main program?
Or the better solution is to create an executable file of each one and load them in the main program?
Or even better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you read [Code Complete](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) or something simlar. This book and others go into the best practices or even how to know which of the best practices you should look into when you create a product.

The problem is one of scope. You need to know your specifications and the parts that join together, as well as which design practices you are going to use before you can answer this question.

I am also inclined to think that there is no right or wrong answer (depending on HOW wrong you are) and that no-one else can answer that question for you, especially since you are likely to be one of the main players in maintaining the code.

Hope that gives you some food for thought :-)

Comment: Thank u dear Daniel :). Can you suggest some other books like one that u mentioned above. Books that teaches someone how to use his ability to write greater code. Or how to write biiig :D softwares. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read