# sql server connection to db

Tags: c#, sql-server

I did some more research and came up with something else. However, this time the message box shows that the pwd was changed but when i refreshed the page in the db it was not changed. Here's the code:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection();

sqlconn.ConnectionString = @" ";          
sqlconn.Open();
string empCode = comboEmpCode.Text;
string oldPwd = txtOldPwd.Text;
string newPwd = txtNewPwd.Text;
string confirmPwd = txtConNewPwd.Text;
string sqlquery = "UPDATE [Employee] SET Pwd=@newpass where EmployeeCode=@empcode";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpass", txtNewPwd.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empcode", comboEmpCode.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldPwd", txtOldPwd.Text);
cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if ((txtNewPwd.Text == reader["newPwd"].ToString()) & (txtConNewPwd.Text == (reader["confirmPwd"].ToString()))) { }
}
MessageBox.Show("Password was changed Successfully!", "Password Change", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
this.Close();
```

Comment: Do you actually have a ConnectionString or you are passing @" " in the code?

Comment: Are you using `TransactionScope` anywhere? Or transactions in general anywhere? These might be getting rolled back.

Comment: Why do you have an `@oldPwd` parameter if you are not using it in the query? And what's with the `ExecuteReader`? That will not return anything.

Comment: Did the change hit the database?

Comment: I don't see where in your Update statement you are using the "@oldPwd" value, maybe this is causing an error to occur?

Comment: The MessageBox will always show unless an exception is thrown. Use try/catch.

Comment: Also have you tried using SQL Profiler to see exactly what is being sent down the pipe?

Comment: Please don't post the details of your question in a separate question. The original is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034351/creating-a-sql-connection-in-c-sharp. You could also use a better title. How many different question on this site could use the same title?

Comment: @Oded, not to my knowledge. Malkassem yes the connection string is actually there. i just removed it. John, i tried to post this in a comment but it was too much characters so i was advised to post a new question.

Comment: If you need to add detail, it is best to _edit_ the existing question rather than post a new one.

Comment: @Oded, point taken. Will do for future posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this method it returns a true if the update was successful and a false if it wasn't successful, I added the message boxes to provide a little clarity during troubleshooting. Additionally, I wrapped your SQLConnection and SQLCommand objects in Using statements which should properly dispose of these objects nicely when you are done which them.

```
public bool ChangePassword(string empCode, string newPassword, string oldPassword)
{
    string connectionString = "@<Enter your Connection String Here>";

    string sql = "UPDATE [Employee] SET Pwd=@newpass where EmployeeCode=@empcode";

    if (oldPassword != newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpass", newPassword);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empcode", empCode);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}-{1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Your New password {0}, can not be the same as the old password {1}. Please try again.", newPassword, oldPassword));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it and it didnt work. I kept clicking the 'change password' button but nothing worked.. I also changed the comboEmpCode.Text in my code to comboEmpCode.SelectedItem because its a combobox but i got a error msg abt parameterized queries. Also, the combo box is not showing the employee codes altho i bounded them to it. Another thing too i got error msgs about my 'private void' functions after i inserted your code.

Comment: I would try hard coding the variables to see where the code is breaking and then work from there.